# How to continuously poll an API for a specific outcome in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, http, promise

I have made an HTTP PUT request to an API, which returns the response state as "waiting". I want to keep polling the API with HTTP GET requests until the state changes to "finished". I am using promises in NodeJS and haven't found a solution that continuously polls my requests.

I have tried using Promise Chaining using setTimeout() but that does not poll the API, rather requests as many times as I've written the code for HTTP GET. I want to use something like:

```
while(JSON.parse(response.body).result.info.state != "finished")
{
  //keep polling
}
```

I should see polling GET requests on the API console, but the while loop only runs once.

```
startRequest(request, reply) {

    console.log("startRequest() is fired")
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            setTimeout(function () {
                Request.put({ //making a PUT request (i have done require('request'))
                    headers: {
                        "SessionID": request.payload.session
                    },
                    url: "http://" + API - IP + ":" + API - PORT + "/upload/" + request.payload.filenameWithoutExtension,

                }, (error, response) => {
                    if (error)
                        reject(error);
                    else {
                        var state = JSON.parse(response.body).result.info.state;
                        var pendingid = JSON.parse(response.body).result.info.id;
                        console.log("response.body", response.body)
                        resolve(state + ":" + pendingid);
                    }
                })
            }, 3 * 1000)
        }).then(response => { //then with response making a GET request

                var infoArray = response.split(":")
                var pendingid = infoArray[1];

                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        console.log("Polling() is fired")
                        while (state != "finished") {
                            Request.get({
                                headers: {
                                    "SessionID": request.payload.session
                                },
                                url: "http://" + API - IP + ":" + API - PORT + "/pending/" + pendingid,

                            }, (error, response) => {
                                if (error)
                                    reject(error);
                                else {
                                    state = JSON.parse(response.body).result.info.state;
                                    return state;
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @Bob I want to send repeated HTTP GET requests based on the response that comes in the HTTP PUT request. Normally the response is "waiting" state. I want to fire the same HTTP GET requests until I get "finished" state.

Comment: You cannot use a `while` loop with asynchronous stuff (unless you go for `async`/`await` syntax). Try a recursive approach.

Comment: @Bergi how can i use Async /await syntax in this scenario?

Comment: @DevSenGoku Just [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57213121/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi would try this and get back to you. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Bob I have just commented on the usage of `while` with asynchronous code. I agree that polling has more load than other approaches, but it's not per se "wrong". Doing one request to upload data, then doing another request to inquire the progress of processing is relatively common. Using polling (instead of SSE or a websocket) might not be optimal, but it seems like the OP's API chose that way.

Comment: @Bob Of course he shouldn't start the polling before the PUT request has succeeded. I didn't look closely enough at the code, is he actually doing that?

Comment: @Bergi on closer inspection it appears the OP is polling an application API for a submission status as opposed to a basic initial "put" request. ( comments removed and solution suggested. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in general, to effect

```
while(variable !== value){
    asynchronousFunction(callback(){

    });       
}
```

as might be expected if asynchronousFunction was being executed synchronously, you can use ;

```
f(){
    if(variable !== value){ // do the loop condition test
        asynchronousFunction(callback(){ //call the loop contents
            variable = updated_value ;// set the condition variable in the callback - ie. when asynchronousFunction is done. then..
            f() // call again - ie. loop with the updated condition variable
        });         
    }
}

f() ; // start the loop
```

though things are a bit more complicated here because of Promises and timeouts ;

Try

```
startRequest(request, reply) {
    console.log("startRequest() is fired")

    const pollingDelay = 1000 ;
    let state = null ;
    let pendingid = null ;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Request.put({ //making a PUT request (i have done require('request'))
                headers: {
                    "SessionID": request.payload.session
                },
                url: "http://" + API - IP + ":" + API - PORT + "/upload/" + request.payload.filenameWithoutExtension

            }, (error, response) => {
                if (error)
                    reject(error);
                else {
                    state = JSON.parse(response.body).result.info.state;
                    pendingid = JSON.parse(response.body).result.info.id;
                    console.log("response.body", response.body)
                    resolve(state + ":" + pendingid);
                }
            });
        }).then(response => { //then with response making a GET request
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {                                            

                function pollState(){
                    console.log("Polling...")
                    Request.get({
                        headers: {
                            "SessionID": request.payload.session
                        },
                        url: "http://" + API - IP + ":" + API - PORT + "/pending/" + pendingid

                    }, (error, response) => {
                        if (error)
                            reject(error);
                        else {
                            state = JSON.parse(response.body).result.info.state;
                            continueCheckingForCompletion();
                        }
                    });                        
                }

                function continueCheckingForCompletion(){
                    if(state !== "finished")){
                        setTimeout(pollState,pollingDelay);
                    }
                    else{
                        resolve(state);
                    }
                }

                continueCheckingForCompletion();
            });
    });
}
```

**Disclaimer**

This code (a modification of the OP code) is only intended to address the problem of calling an asynchronous function (get) repeatedly until a given condition is met (state === "finished").

Whether it is the right code for the task depends on the specifics of the Request package and the server API.

**Notes**

Checking a "pending" endpoint for "finished" doesn't seem intuitive. Also, in the event the submission is accepted but is not subsequently finished for some reason, the "pending" endpoint would need to raise an error to indicate the process had failed as otherwise the polling will continue indefinitely.

A more intuitive RESTful API for this type of client-use would be ;

```
/upload/<upload info> //success returns submission id

/status/<submissionId> // success returns current status - used for polling

/pending/[target identifier] //returns 404 - not here or the target if present in pending or discovery info if no target identifier.

/finished/[target identifier] //returns 404 - not here or the target if present in finished or discovery info if no target identifier.
```

Comment: Mate you are a genius! I followed your method and could poll the request successfully, and was able to parse the result out of the response. Just had to give a try-catch block around JSON.parse().