# Promise to async await when polling

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I'm trying to convert a function that uses promise (and polling) to an async function, but I'm not really sure how it works.

I have this:

```
function myFunction() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // stuff here ...

        var poll = setInterval(function() {
            if (condition) {
                clearInterval(poll);
                resolve("done");
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

.. but I'm unsure what to `await` here:

```
async function myFunction() {
    // stuff here ...

    var poll = setInterval(function() {
        if (condition) {
            clearInterval(poll);
            // await what?
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval` does not play nice with async await. It is best to use a 'promisified' version of setTimeout that you call again on each iteration of the loop.

```
const myFunction = async = () => {
  let condition = false;

  while (!condition) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
    condition = processCondition();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
async function myFunction() {
    // stuff here ...
    var poll = await setInterval(function() {
        if (condition) {
            clearInterval(poll);
            // await what?
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  You `await` a promise, not a timerID (which is what `setInterval()` returns.